# How to cross compile for the PS3 from Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, playstation3

Has anyone done this before, and if so how do you setup the development environment?

Answer (score 1):

You need the official PS3 SDK, which costs around $10,000. They include all the instructions with it, I am sure.

Comment: I want to target the a PS3 Linux distro like Yellow Dog Linux, but I'd like to do all the development on my Mac, cross compile, then run the app on PS3 Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the PS3 does support Linux (Fedora Core 8); it's not the newest distribution in the world, but if you want to write your own code targeting the PS3 that's a place to start.